# Use a function to generate reactive values in a reactiveValues object in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I have numerous reactive elements to create in a `{Shiny}` `reactiveValues` object, all requiring almost identical filtering code. But I cannot work out how to do this efficiently, i.e. without writing the filtering code directly for each element. In the sample code below, a radio button controls filtering of some data into 2 groups, A and B. The difference between the good and bad outputs is that the bad one uses a function to define its value, whereas the good one has it specified directly as a `reactive` object.

When using the function to create the value for the bad one, it seems to be stuck at the intial value, as when changing the data by selecting a different group it does not change. The good one does correctly filter the data however. So how could we create many elements with the same code in the `reactiveValues` object?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(
    "group", "",
    list(A = "A", B = "B"), list("A"),
    inline = TRUE
  ),
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  textOutput("filtered_data_bad"),
  textOutput("filtered_data_good")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- tibble(
    group = rep(c("A", "B"), c(5, 10))
  )

  group_saved <- reactiveVal(value = c("A"))

  observeEvent(
    input$go,
    group_saved(input$group),
    ignoreInit = TRUE,
    ignoreNULL = FALSE
  )

  filter_data <- function (.data, .group) {
    reactive(
      .data[.data$group %in% .group,]
    )
  }

  format_text <- function (.data, .group) {
    req(nrow(.data) > 0)
    paste(
      "Selected:",
      nrow(.data),
      "total"
    )
  }

  rv <- reactiveValues(
    bad  = filter_data(data, group_saved()),
    good = reactive(
      data[data$group %in% group_saved(),]
    )
  )

  output$filtered_data_bad <- renderText({
    format_text(rv$bad(), group_saved())
  })

  output$filtered_data_good <- renderText({
    format_text(rv$good(), group_saved())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code above is as simple as I could get it while showing the issue. I am working with the requirement to be able to select many different groups simultaneously from a common pool of choices (geographical regions in fact), for which the `reactiveValues` will hold one set of choices per group. Each group has its own `reactiveVal` object (`saved_regions_A`, `saved_regions_B`, ...) that serves as the filter.

```
regions_saved_A <- reactiveVal(value = regions)
regions_saved_B <- reactiveVal(value = NULL)
regions_saved_C <- reactiveVal(value = NULL)
...

filter_data <- function (.data, .regions) {
  reactive(.data %>% filter(region %in% .regions))
}

filtered_data <- reactiveValues(
  A = filter_data(data, regions_saved_A()),
  B = filter_data(data, regions_saved_B()),
  C = filter_data(data, regions_saved_C()),
  ...
)
```

I have tried removing the `reactive` call from the function and calling it with the function call for each value (it seems to be needed as I am relying on a `reactiveVal` for the saved choices). None of the below work:

```
filter_data <- function (.data, .regions) {
  .data %>% filter(region %in% .regions)
}

filtered_data <- reactiveValues(
  A = reactive(filter_data(data, regions_saved_A())),
  B = filter_data(data, regions_saved_B()),
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the `reactiveValues` in an `observer`. No need to make them reactive again. Try this

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(
    "group", "",
    list(A = "A", B = "B"), list("A"),
    inline = TRUE
  ),
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  textOutput("filtered_data_bad"),
  textOutput("filtered_data_good")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- tibble(
    group = rep(c("A", "B"), c(5, 10))
  )
  
  group_saved <- reactiveVal(value = c("A"))
  
  observeEvent(
    input$go,
    group_saved(input$group),
    ignoreInit = TRUE,
    ignoreNULL = FALSE
  )
  
  filter_data <- function (df, .group) {
    df[df$group %in% .group,]
    
    # reactive(
    #   .data[.data$group %in% .group,]
    # )
    
  }
  
  format_text <- function (.data, .group) {
    req(nrow(.data) > 0)
    paste(
      "Selected:",
      nrow(.data),
      "total"
    )
  }
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(bad=NULL,good=NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    group_saved()
    rv$bad  = filter_data(data, group_saved())
    rv$good = data[data$group %in% group_saved(),]
  })
  
  output$filtered_data_bad <- renderText({
    req(rv$bad)
    format_text(rv$bad, group_saved())
  })
  
  output$filtered_data_good <- renderText({
    req(rv$good)
    format_text(rv$good, group_saved())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks @YBS, I can see this resolves the issue with this simple example. Unfortunately it does not work when I try using it in the real code. If I add this to my question do you mind having another look pls?

Comment: I spoke too soon, works perfectly!